# Taking long list of repeated values and copying to sorted, unique list

Tags: numbers

Alrighty, I’m working on some homespun financial rejiggering. I have a manually-entered “**Keyword**” column that features many repeated values.

A small sampling:

- Cleaners
- Cleaners
- Cleaners
- Cell
- Cell
- Cell
- Cell
- Cell
- Cable
- Cable
- Cable
- Cable
- Band
- Band
- ATM Fee
- ATM Fee
- ATM Fee
- ATM Fee
- ATM Fee
- ATM Fee
- Amazon
- Amazon
- Amazon
- Amazon
- Amazon
- Amazon
- Amazon

I need to create either another column OR table that takes these many values, de-dupes them and sorts them alphabetically, like this:

- Cleaners
- Cell
- Cable
- Band
- ATM Fee
- Amazon

This needs to be done with  formula… not manually or scripted.

Suggestions??

Comment: AppleScript and JavaScript can extract data, sort, inject in a new table. Why cut off the best way to do this?

Comment: Where do I start with incorporating JS? I could do that in a heartbeat. It just doesn't run real-time with updates, right? And do you have examples?

Comment: Start with [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508) and Sal Saghoian's site https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript uses terms from the [AppleScript Toolbox plug-in](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/) to function correctly.

I copied your list of duplicates and pasted them between the double quotes in the first line of my code

```
set theList to paragraphs of "Cleaners\nCleaners\nCleaners\nCell\nCell\nCell\nCell\nCell\nCable\nCable\nCable\nCable\nBand\nBand\nATM Fee\nATM Fee\nATM Fee\nATM Fee\nATM Fee\nATM Fee\nAmazon\nAmazon\nAmazon\nAmazon\nAmazon\nAmazon\nAmazon"
set noDupes to AST copy list theList with sorting items without keeping duplicates
set text item delimiters to {linefeed}
set theList2 to noDupes as text
set theList2 to reverse of paragraphs of theList2
set the clipboard to theList2 as text
```

Will return A new list without the duplicates and copy it to your clipboard:

- Cleaners
- Cell
- Cable
- Band
- ATM Fee
- Amazon

Answer (score 0):

[image: compoundcriteria]

You can using Access, I dont know if this is what your looking for but it is one way to do it.

Comment: Access is Windows only at this point no? Also quite expensive. Thanks for your contribution, though! Cheers